# Issue with sticky js script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using this plugin/code: http://labs.anthonygarand.com/sticky/ on my website: http://www.jkogden.net/ocdb/games/

If you go to my website and scroll down, you'll notice that the right hand sidebar scrolls too- that part works great. However, when you're at the top of the screen, you can't click on any of links unless you scroll down some.

I did not see this as a problem on their demo page(s). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the declaration of :

```
#container-content-right-side, #container-content-right-side-ocdb
```

You have

```
z-index: -1;
```

Remove it, or put `z-index: 1;` and it'll work (i checked it using live inspection)

Comment: I did see that. Better solution. +1

Comment: You are correct, however, -1 puts that box "behind" the main content box. Is there any other way to correct this?

Comment: I was able to correct it. Thank you both for pointing me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the plugin is doing this, but if you put this css rule it will works fine:

```
#container-content-right-side-ocdb-sticky-wrapper { height: 1px !important; }
```

Poor answer, but it works...

The plugin wrap your content with a div and give the above id for it. Apparently it use that div just as a anchor for the page, but it set the height of the div to 430px, and this is the problem.